# Force Computer Modern in math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode, beamer, xetex, computer-modern

I am writing a presentation using the beamer class and XeTeX. I have changed the sans font using `\setsansfont`. Now *some* symbols in my equations are rendered using the mono font (like the lowercase letters).

How can I force math mode to render all symbols in the equations in the default Computer Modern, ignoring the font set with `\setsansfont`?

Comment: Could you pleas edit your question and add that you are seeing this behavior with beamer slides. That would be helpful for people having the same problem and searching for a solution.

Comment: I changed the tags.

Answer (score 7):

By default, Beamer does some math font manipulation, because many fonts, such as the cm-sans used by default, don't provide matching mathematical glyphs. If you want the standard Computer Modern (serif) math font, just say

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

in the preamble. This suppresses any auto-manipulations.

Comment: Note that you don't have to (and in fact shouldn't) sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: I was looking into changing only the math font for the `metropolis` theme. This solution works much better than fiddling with the package`unicode-math`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it was a beamer issue. Using

```
\documentclass[onlymath]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
```

solves the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, though.

Comment: Yes. I didn't noitce it is `beamer` here.

Comment: And you'd use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage[cm-default,no-math]{fontspec}
```

Comment: This change makes *more* symbols appear in the sans font, instead of the less, e.g. now numbers are in the sans font. Could this be a beamer issue?